# Linux tools for measuring disk i/o etc

Tags: linux, profiling, performance-testing

I need to measure the utilization of following resources on RedHat and CentOS during my performance testing. Please suggest the best tools

- Memory usage
- CPU usage
- Disk I/O
- Network I/O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory Usage :

`free` is great, but `htop` will actually answer your CPU usage question, also.

For Disk I/O, `iotop` is probably what you want - but there is also `iostat`, `atop` and `glances`

As for Network I/O - I prefer `slurm` - but there is also `iftop`

But there are literally tons of tools at your disposal, and they each have their own pros and cons - I've given you my favorites, but there are plenty more that you may like even more than the ones I've mentioned, thus far.

So, do your research. Read some manuals. Google is your friend. `man` is the best tool you will ever use.

These packages are also highly notable: 
`vmstat`, `lsof`,`netstat`,`iptraf`,`monit`,`nethogs`

There are other great ones like `nmon`, `collectl`, and `monitorix` ---

Hopefully these links will always work, but if they don't, I listed the notable packages each one mentions (RTFM):

http://kkovacs.eu/cool-but-obscure-unix-tools

```
dstat
sar
htop
atop
glances
slurm
iftop
iptraf
nethogs
```

http://www.tecmint.com/command-line-tools-to-monitor-linux-performance/

```
vmstat
lsof
tcpdump (ngrep)
netstat
htop
iotop
iostat
iptraf
psacct / acct
monit
nethogs
iftop
monitorix
arpwatch
suricata
vnstat
nagios
nmon
collectctl
```

http://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-monitor-network/

```
nload
iftop
iptraf
nethogs
bmon
slurm
tcptrack
vnstat
bwm-ng
cbn
pkstat
netwatch
trafshow
netload
ifstat
dstat
collectl
```

Answer (score 1):

[Glances](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances) allows you to monitoring:

- Memory usage
- CPU usage
- Disk I/O
- Network I/O

and also:

- Load
- Processes (per process MEM, CPU, DIsk IO)
- Filesystem space
- Sensors

in a single CLI interface:

[image]